# Adding field to entity via .install file doesn't add field to table

Tags: 8, entities

Attempting to add a field to a commerce_promotion_coupon with the following in commerce_promotion.install:

```
function commerce_promotion_update_8204() {
  $entity_definition_update = \Drupal::entityDefinitionUpdateManager();

  $storage_definition = BaseFieldDefinition::create('boolean')
    ->setLabel(t('Bulk'))
    ->setDescription(t('Indicates if coupon is bulk.'))
    ->setDefaultValue(0);
  $entity_definition_update->installFieldStorageDefinition('bulk', 'commerce_promotion_coupon', 'commerce_promotion', $storage_definition);
}
```

Running `drush updb` completes successfully, but the field isn't in the database - what am I doing wrong?

Comment: You cannot add base field like this. You can either use it in the hook_entity_base_field_info() or create FieldConfig entity instead.

Comment: You can, but I missed the other half which is the field must also be added to  Coupon::baseFieldDefinitions, I'll come back and post an answer shortly.